# Not in Order when using Masonry Layout using css grid

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, masonry

I'm trying to create layout of 2 columns using masonry layout in grid system. Each Item may have multiple links and descriptions. So that I tried using masonry layout avoid gap in rows.

But the item are not in order (Left to Right). In the below pic first item as multiple links to its occupied two rows. So that 3rd item wrap to 2nd column.

How can i avoid that 3rd item shouldn't wrap to 2nd column. It's should be in left to right or Odd items on left and even on right.

How can anyone help me with this please.

```js
let productList={
    resizeAllGridItems: function(){
        allItems = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
        for(x=0;x<allItems.length;x++){
            resizeGridItem(allItems[x]);
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    productList.resizeAllGridItems();
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        productList.resizeAllGridItems
    });
});
function resizeGridItem(item){
    grid = document.getElementsByClassName("grid")[0];
    rowHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(grid).getPropertyValue('grid-auto-rows'));
    rowGap = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(grid).getPropertyValue('grid-row-gap'));
    console.log(rowHeight,rowGap,(item.querySelector('.content').getBoundingClientRect().height+rowGap))
    rowSpan = Math.ceil((item.querySelector('.content').getBoundingClientRect().height+rowGap)/(rowHeight+rowGap));
        item.style.gridRowEnd = "span "+rowSpan;
}
function resizeInstance(instance){
    item = instance.elements[0];
    resizeGridItem(item);
}
```

```css
.container{
            max-width:640px;
        }
        .grid {
            display: grid;
            grid-gap: 50px 40px;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px,1fr));
            grid-auto-rows: 40px;
        }
        body {
            margin: 10px;
            color: #374046;
            background-color: #fff;
            font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.15em;
            text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        }
        .item {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
        .product-link{
            font-size: larger;
        }
        .desc{
            padding-right:10px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="title">
                        <p>Index-Lined Annuity -1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <a class="product-link" href="#">Flex Item -></a>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <p>Flex Item Description</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <a class="product-link" href="#">Flex Item -></a>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <p>Flex Item Description</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <a class="product-link" href="#">Flex Item -></a>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <p>Flex Item Description</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="title">
                        <p>Single Premium Income Annuity -2 </p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <a class="product-link" href="#">Flex Item -></a>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <p>Flex Item Description</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="title">
                        <p>Variable Annuity -3</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <a class="product-link" href="#">Flex Item -></a>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <p>Flex Item Description</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="title">
                        <p>Fixed Rate Annuity -4</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a class="product-link" href="#">Flex Item -></a>
                        <div class="desc">
                            <p>Flex Item Description</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="title">
                        <p>Deffered Annuity -5</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <a class="product-link" href="#">Flex Item -></a>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <p>Flex Item Description</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3U9e.png)